How do I get current Selection of my Document?
I am using Visual Studio 2022 and I have created a VSTO Word Add-In project.
Hello everyone, I want to insert a newly created table at the user's current cursor position in the Word document. How can I get the current selection from the document? In a recent Word Web Add-In project, I used the JavaScript function context.document.getSelection();. Is there an equivalent in the C# API for my Word document?
Word-Web-Add-In project:
    async function insertTableData() {
        await Word.run(async (context) => {
            const thisDocument = context.document;
            const range = thisDocument.getSelection();
            await context.sync();
        }).catch(){};
    }

Word-VSTO-Add-In project:
Word.Document ThisDocument = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
Word.Range tableLocation = ThisDocument.Range(0, 0);
Word.Table AddedTable = ThisDocument.Tables.Add(tableLocation, 3, 4);

I have been looking into the documentation, but it’s quite a lot, and I might have just missed the entry for getSelection().
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection?view=word-pia

OTTOMH I think you have to use something like selection = Globals.ThisDocument.Application.Selection , see, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/global-access-to-objects-in-office-projects?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp .
